# Why do I got this error: error: too few type arguments

Tags: interface, vala

I am learning Vala programming and I got this error message.

```
inter.vala:9.55-9.65: error: too few type arguments
public class Totumfaktum : GLib.Object, ITotumfaktum, Traversable {
                                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^
Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

The source code is below.

using Gee;

```
public interface ITotumfaktum : GLib.Object, Traversable {
    public abstract int data_1 { get; set; }
    public abstract int ret();
    public abstract void stat();
}

public class Totumfaktum : GLib.Object, ITotumfaktum, Traversable {
    public int data_1 { get; set; }
    public int ret() {
        stdout.printf("\nRET\n");
        return 0;
    }
    public void stat() {
        return;
    }
}

static int main(string[] args) {
    Totumfaktum t = new Totumfaktum();
    t.ret();

    ITotumfaktum s = t;
    t.ret();
    return 0;
}
```

Debian 10, Vala 0.42.5

Answer (score 1):

[`Gee.Traversable`](https://valadoc.org/gee-0.8/Gee.Traversable.html) is a generic type, so you need to provide type arguments.

For example, if the type for each element is `int`, you would use `Gee.Traversable<int>`.

For a more thorough example, check out: https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/Manual/Generics

Comment: Thanks You for reply!

Comment: @urandom0 Happy to help! If you feel the answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on posts which still don't have answers.